# Date format in source flat file (Source)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

We need a date format that works with this date:

6/25/2022 12:57:37.733 PM

The data source is a flat file, once the process is executed, the data is rejected by the date format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do you need the millisecond from string? if not, i have a solution.

Comment: Date has no format - it's a number. The string representation has a format. What is your target and what are its settings?